# how to get the ACTUAL execution time of a "method" using Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

Hi can anyone help me in this issue

*>I am **executing a method of a Java class using Java Reflection**.Now i want to get the **real execution time of a method regardless the time taken by reflection**.*

**class AClass {**
//method

**void abc(){
System.out.println("Hello World");
}**

*//Now using reflection i am going to invoke this method*

**AClass aObj=new AClass();**

**Class _cObj=Class.forName("AClass");** 
**Method _meth_Invoke=cObj.getMethod("abc",null);**

*//Now hear as u see that if i take time Stamp before executing this (Method.invoke())statement and then after take another time stamp and subtract it(using "System.nanoTime()" ), then i get the TIME of both methods abc()+  invoke()  method.And thats the problem that i just want to get know the actual execution time of Method abc().*

**_meth_Invoke.invoke(aObj,...);
}**

Kindly guide me i spent a lot of time on surfing but cant fine the right material for it.

Comment: You can just create a `new Date()`, call the method, create another `new Date()` and find the time difference

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler to find out how much time the program is spending executing the method. If you're using Oracle's JDK 6 (or newer), you could use [JVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) which is included with the JDK for profiling.

Start it by entering the command `jvisualvm` in a command prompt window.

Comment: i want to do it programmaticly not with the help of any tool or library kidly give some other direction of help

Answer (score 0):

The cost of calling a Method via reflection is typically sub-microsecond.  You can benchmark this on your machine to confirm this.  If you are trying to benchmark a method which is less than 10 micro-seconds this is very hard to do accurately. If its much more than this I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: kindly tell me the way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time it takes to call an empty method (`void xyz() {}`) via reflection and subtract it from the time you measured calling the `abc()` method via reflection.
This is as accurate as you can get programmatically.

Otherwise you have to use a profiler like JVisualVM.